How near are a groupoid and its 'preorderification'?
As remarks, a groupoid is a category with only (categorical) isomorphisms as its morphisms and a preorder is a category only having one morphism between each object. If we choose one isomorphism by choice or use 'there is an isomorphism' as a morphism, a 'preorderification' of its groupoid can be defined I think. My question is how far there is a relationship between these categories from a model-theoretic or category-theoretic perspective.
To give an example, let me take elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$. Of course, the category having such elliptic curves as objects and isomorphisms as morphisms is groupoid. In this, I define a choosing function $c$, as a function of that if we have an isomorphism from $E_1$ to $E_2$, $f(x, y) = (\lambda^2 x + r, \lambda ^3 y + s)$ with the least values of $\lambda$, $r$ and $s$ using the Weierstrass forms derived from Riemman-Roch. (Possibly other choice functions can be opted for.) I believe that this $c$ satisfies the composable condition which means $c(f \circ g) = c(f) \circ c(g)$. By this, we could get the 'preorderification' of the groupoid of elliptic curves and there is a functor from the groupoid to the preorder. Unfortunately, this functor is not faithful so a fortiori not categorical equivalent. On top of that, the preorder loses the information of $Aut(E)$, which is isomorphic to certain cyclic groups depending on the j-invariant. However, even so, if we want the isomorphism class of elliptic curves, these categories are the 'same' since whatever we take an isomorphism among them, all isomorphism classes are completely tantamount.
So I am intrigued in this riddle. If you answer this question, I appreciate for it with strongness. Thanks in advance!

There isn't an interesting preorder structure, you just get an equivalence relation and lose information about automorphisms.

I am in a position learning about maths, so my perspective may not be precise, but I agree with you. Even so I wonder there is a situation to use groupoids is 'overkilling'. For example, there is an argument about the isomorphism classes of elliptic curves and it is not required to people using groupoids but sufficient use the preorder. It may be happened to deceive people with unnecessary definition as if 'the set of isomorphisms is needed'. This is only my motivation directly unrelated to the question, though.

It's hard to answer, because whether or not it's important to remember automorphisms depends very much in the context and what you want to do. In geometry, this distinction between groupoids and equivalence relations becomes the distinction between moduli stacks and coarse moduli spaces. If you want to think about families of objects, then you absolutely need to remember automorphisms and think about the moduli stack. However, the coarse moduli space is a much more concrete object to think about and is enough for some purposes, so sometimes you don't want to bother with stacks.

To reuse your elliptic curves example: the moduli stack is a Deligne-Mumford stack, whose underlying moduli space is the modular curve; the stack remembers the extra data of the elliptic points and their finite automorphism group. If you look at Diamond-Shurman, they study the moduli curves in great detail without ever saying the word stack; this is fine since most of the book is focused on weight 2 modular forms, which happen to be the same as differentials on the modular curve. However, modular forms of higher weight should really be thought of as section of line bundles on the moduli stack.

I don't see how your $f$ is well-defined. It would be if you considered the category of non-singular Weierstrass equations. Using Riemann-Roch involves choosing $x$ and $y$, which amounts to choosing your equation. (And it should be $(\lambda^2x+r, \lambda^3 y + s\lambda^2x + t$).

Unfortunately, this functor is not faithful so a fortiori not categorical equivalent this will be true whenever you have any object x in your groupoid that has Aut(x) nontrivial. That is, this functor is only faithful when you are starting with an equivalence relation, and then the functor will be at worst an isomorphism, and at best the identity map. There is always a functor from a groupoid G to its preorderification R as an abstract thing: there is only one possible function Hom_G(x,y) -> Hom_R(x,y) in every case, and preservation of composition etc follow trivially.

Making a choice of subgroupoid R' of G isomorphic to R such that there is an identity-on-objects retraction G -> R' is not trivial. If G -> R has an adjoint you might try, but this is rather strong.
